# SQL Server: Select records which have any HTML entities within a VARCHAR(MAX) column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a table `MyTable(id INT, stringText varchar(max))` with over 2 million records. 
I would like to write a query to analyse the number of rows which have any of the following characters (HTML Entities) within the text.

```
&#12288;
&#160;
&#61623;
&#64257;
&#64258;
&#8217;
&#x00A0;
&#x2013;
&#x2014;
&#x2019;
&#x201C;
&#x2022;
&euro;
&sbquo;
&fnof;
&bdquo;
&hellip;
&dagger;
&Dagger;
&circ;
&permil;
&Scaron;
&lsaquo;
&OElig;
&Zcaron;
&lsquo;
&rsquo;
&ldquo;
&rdquo;
&bull;
&ndash;
&mdash;
&tilde;
&trade;
&scaron;
&rsaquo;
&oelig;
&zcaron;
&Yuml;
&iexcl;
&cent;
&pound;
&curren;
&yen;
&brvbar;
&sect;
&uml;
&copy;
&ordf;
&laquo;
&not;
&reg;
&macr;
&deg;
&plusmn;
&sup2;
&sup3;
&acute;
&micro;
&para;
&middot;
&cedil;
&sup1;
&ordm;
&raquo;
&frac14;
&frac12;
&frac34;
&iquest;
&Agrave;
&Aacute;
&Acirc;
&Atilde;
&Auml;
&Aring;
&AElig;
&Ccedil;
&Egrave;
&Eacute;
&Ecirc;
&Euml;
&Igrave;
&Iacute;
&Icirc;
&Iuml;
&ETH;
&Ntilde;
&Ograve;
&Oacute;
&Ocirc;
&Otilde;
&Ouml;
&times;
&Oslash;
&Ugrave;
&Uacute;
&Ucirc;
&Uuml;
&Yacute;
&THORN;
&szlig;
&agrave;
&aacute;
&acirc;
&atilde;
&auml;
&aring;
&aelig;
&ccedil;
&egrave;
&eacute;
&ecirc;
&euml;
&igrave;
```

Could someone help me in writing an efficient `WHERE CLAUSE` to find out the number of rows, please?

I tried something like below, but it doesn't give me the expected results.

```
DECLARE @testStr AS VARCHAR(MAX) = 'testing - quote chars and others '+ '&quot;' + '&#12288;'+ '&#160;' + '&#61623;' + '- testing'
DECLARE @temp TABLE (string VARCHAR(MAX));
INSERT INTO @temp(string) VALUES ('testing - plain text'), (@testStr), ('testing' + CHAR(1) + CHAR(2) + CHAR(3) + CHAR(4)+ ' testing 1-4'), ('sathish' + CHAR(1) + ' testing - char 1'), ('sathish' + CHAR(3) + CHAR(4)+ ' testing - char 3-4')

SELECT * FROM @temp WHERE string LIKE '%[' + CHAR(1) + CHAR(2) + CHAR(3) + CHAR(4) + ']%' /* this where clause works fine, i.e. only returns the rows with any of those characters*/
SELECT * FROM @temp WHERE string LIKE '%[' + '&quot;' + '&#12288;' + '&#160;' + '&#61623;' + ']%' /* this where clause doesn't work as expected, it is returning all rows*/
```

I assume the `WHERE CLAUSE` in my second `SQL` query didn't work because there was more than one character within in single quotes (which makes it a string rather than a character).

Thank you in advance.

**Note:** 1. The data is already in the database (please don't ask why this wasn't handled before saving into the database) and I cannot use SQL CLR functions, unfortunately.

2. I would like to avoid multiple OR clauses something like below:

> ```
> SELECT * FROM @temp 
> WHERE string LIKE '%&quot;' 
> OR string LIKE '%&#12288;%' 
> OR string LIKE '%&#160;%' 
> OR string LIKE '5&#61623;%' -- and so on
> ```

Answer (score 2):

You can try with all your entities as string elements in the **IN** part of the WHERE CLAUSE

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @temp
WHERE SUBSTRING(
   string, 
   PATINDEX('%&%',string),
   PATINDEX('%;%',string) - PATINDEX('%&%',string) + 1
) IN ('&Eacute;', '&Ecirc;', '&Euml;', '&Igrave;', '&Iacute;',
 '...', '...' ,a.s.o)
```

or use a special entities-table, where you insert all your entities. Then your **IN** part would look like this

```
IN (SELECT entities FROM entities-table)
```

As I have no way to test, I can only propose a  possible improvement, so that the found ';' is behind the found '&'

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @temp
WHERE SUBSTRING(
   string, 
   PATINDEX('%&%',string),
   PATINDEX('%;%',  SUBSTRING(string, PATINDEX('%&%',string), max ) - PATINDEX('%&%',string) + 1
) IN ('&Eacute;', '&Ecirc;', '&Euml;', '&Igrave;', '&Iacute;',
```

Comment: It looks like something is wrong with your SQL Script, please can you correct it?

Comment: It would be great if you could adjust your query to use with my example (@temp table variable) so I can extend it as required for my real table.

Comment: I have tried that, but it is throwing an error `'string' is not a recognized built-in function name.` `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @temp
WHERE string(
   string, 
   PATINDEX('%&%',string),
   PATINDEX('%;%',line) - PATINDEX('%&%',line) + 1
) IN ('&Eacute;', '&Ecirc;', '&Euml;', '&Igrave;', '&Iacute;')`

Comment: Sorry, I mixed your original and your intermediate table. You can use your real table by replacing @temp and string. Have a look at the revised version.

Comment: Thank you for correcting the SQL. I will give a try.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is use the `OR` in your `WHERE` clause, like this:

```
SELECT * FROM @temp 
WHERE string LIKE '%&quot;%' 
OR string LIKE '%&#12288;%' 
OR string LIKE '%&#160;%' -- etc.
```

Comment: I think OP tries to do one LIKE on a concatenated string (i.e .all values at once.)

Comment: @roryap: Thank you for your answer. I would be interested to know if there are any other alternatives.

Comment: No, I think that's probably the easiest way.  You could create the query easily enough with an advanced text editor like UltraEdit or Notepad++ using their find and replace features.